# What is the Name of this effect

Tags: effects, special-effects

http://vimeo.com/86969394

I like to know how to do this effect but I don't know what is the term/name for it. The video above around 10 - 12 seconds in with how the title seems fixed to a point in the video despite movement of the camera.

There is also a similar effect if you had watched House of Cards the parts where they are displaying sms messages where the text appears above their phones and moves a bit according to it.

It would be okay to just give me the name of the effect ... I'll do the rest searching for tutorial in YouTube. But a instruction video would also be nice.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like text moving to a "Motion Tracking" effect.

Basically it finds and follows 1 or more points in a picture then moves the text accordingly.

If you use 2 or more points you can track the 3d angle also.

Examples:

**2D position only**

**3D position, scale and angle**